# How to order/ sort relationship models based on their additional relationship's models' values?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have a model Facility that has rates (tariffs). The Rate model has a relationship to a RateType. The RateType has a column `weight`. I want to sort the Facility's rates based on those weights. I would like to always have this ordering so I'd put it into the relationshop function directly. I cant get it to work, though. I always get some mix up with the column and table names and I feel like I am missing a very easy solution.

```
<?php

class Facility extends Model
{
    public function rates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Rate::class)->orderBy(
            // :(
        );
    }
}

class Rate extends Model
{
    public function rateType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RateType::class);
    }
}
```

The RateType doesnt have the relationship function back to Rate, I guess thats not the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just join the table in your `rates` relationship from Facility model, which allows you to call `orderBy` or `orderByDesc` on any `rate_types` column

e.i. (assumed standard column names use by your relationship)

```
class Facility extends Model {

    public function rates() {
        return $this->hasMany(Rate::class)
            ->join('rate_types', 'rate_types.id', '=', 'rates.rate_type_id')
            ->orderBy('rate_types.weight', 'ASC');
            //->orderByDesc('rate_types.weight');
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like

```
return Facility::whereNotNUll('id')->with('rates')->get();
```

which orders automaticaly orders the `rates` relationship

the actual sub-query for the `with` method would look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM rates
INNER JOIN rate_types
ON rate_types.id = rates.rate_type_id
WHERE rates.facility_id in (ids of loaded facilities) 
ORDER BY rate_types.weight
ASC
```

**EDIT**--

For conflicting table names when doing `join`, just alias the column on `select` statement
i.e.

```
return $this->hasMany(Rate::class)
    ->join('rate_types as rt', 'rt.id', '=', 'rates.rate_type_id')
    ->select('*','rt.id as rt_id', ,'rates.id as id') // first select all columns, then add alias on rate_types.id as rt_id
    ->orderBy('rt.weight', 'ASC');
```

e.i

You can select and alias any column name from both `rates` and `rate_types` table like

```
rt.id as rt_id //equals to rate_types.id
```

and

```
rates.id as r_id //equals to rates.id
```

Additionally, another option you can do is to manually select all the columns you would need from both tables so you can omit `rate_types.id` if you dont need it

Comment: Hey @silver, unfortunately this leads me to a problem. When I access my rates like `$facility->rates` the actual items have mixed attributes from their relationship. So the first item from `$facility->rates` should have the id 4, but it has id 1 which is actually the id of the rate's relation's id (rate_type). If I just write `return $this->hasMany(Rate::class)` it is correct but the sorting is gone, obviously. Any idea? The join seems to mix the fields.

Comment: @Alex, thats bound to happen when you join a table that has the same column name, simple remedy is just to alias the columns with duplicate name, I edited my answer and provided an example

Comment: thanks so far! is there an easy way to only get the rate columns? it still merges fields of the rate type into my rate model despite the `select` statement. i really dont want to manually define all the columns. something like `->select('* as *', 'rt.* as rt_*')`

Comment: `->select('rates.*', 'rates.id as id', 'rt.id as rt_id')` did it for me - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to try below code.

```
Facility::with([
'rates' => function($q){
     $q->orderBy('your_column', 'desc');
 }
])->get();
```

Comment: That is neither directly in the relationship function nor does it order by the rate type's weight value (so the relationship of the relationship)